# Meinberg NTPD for Windows timeouts and not finding files

Tags: windows, ntp, ntpd

In my network, I have a reliable NTP server which all PCs are synchronized to. Due to the various problems the Windows Time service is known for (at least in Windows 7 and lower versions), I have disabled it on the Windows machines and instead have installed [Meinberg's port of NTPD for Windows](https://www.meinbergglobal.com/english/sw/ntp.htm).

This has reliably worked for many years on all PCs I ever tested, but today I have got a problem with one of my Windows machines (Windows 7 Pro x64, all updates applied at the time of this writing).

Please note that `C:\Program Files (x86)\NTP\etc\ntp.conf` on that machine is *literally* the same as on all other Windows PCs on that network, except for the last line (see below).

`ntpd.conf` (on the problematic machine, some comments removed):

```
restrict default noquery nopeer nomodify notrap  
restrict -6 default noquery nopeer nomodify notrap  

# allow status queries and everything else from localhost 
restrict 127.0.0.1 
restrict -6 ::1 

# if you need to allow access from a remote host, you can add lines like this: 
# restrict <IP OF REMOTE HOST> 

# Use drift file 
driftfile "C:\Program Files (x86)\NTP\etc\ntp.drift"

# Use specific NTP servers
server timeserver.in.my.local.network iburst minpoll 6 maxpoll 7

# End of generated ntp.conf --- Please edit this to suite your needs

interface ignore wildcard
interface ignore ipv6
interface listen 127.0.0.1
interface listen 192.168.20.100
```

Of course, the last line is is different on different PCs. And yes, I indeed do not want `ntpd` to listen on *each* interface / IP address, but just on the "main" IP address and on `localhost`.

The problem:

As a first quick test I do on every PC after installation, I opened `cmd32` as `administrator` on the PC in question and ran

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\NTP>ntpq -p
```

This resulted in the following error message:

```
ntpq: read: No such file or directory
```

I was first believing what it said and analyzed its behavior with `ProcessMonitor`, but to no avail. I couldn't find any hint that it could not open a file. I scratched my head for a while and then tried

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\NTP>ntpq -p 192.168.20.100
```

This time, I got

```
192.168.20.100: timed out, nothing received
***Request timed out
```

So, obviously, in accordance with my conclusions from `ProcessMonitor`, there is no problem with reading a file, but perhaps with opening the network device.

Weirdly enough,

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\NTP>ntpq -p 127.0.0.1
```

yielded the expected result:

```
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
*192.168.20.10 ( 192.53.103.108   2 u    8  128  377    0.977    0.194   0.977
```

This made me scratch my head again. For testing, I turned off the Windows firewall on that PC (and there is no other firewall installed there), but `ntpq -p` and `ntpq -p 192.168.20.100` still were throwing the same error messages as before.

As a last test, I ran

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\NTP>netstat -abno
```

and got

```
Active Connections

  ...
  UDP    127.0.0.1:123          *:*                                    5076
 [ntpd.exe]    
  ...
  UDP    192.168.20.100:123     *:*                                    5076
 [ntpd.exe]
  ...
```

So `ntpd` listens on the IP addresses from the configuration file as expected.

Of course, restarting the service and even rebooting that PC did not help.

Now I am running out of ideas. What could be the cause that `ntpq` can talk to one of the IP addresses `ntpd` listens on, but not to the other one, even when the firewall is turned off completely?